# Small $R^2$ Despite Clear Difference in Totals Between Groups

Tags: regression, sample-size, r-squared

I have a very large set of products (1000+), each one contributing a certain amount to total revenue.  Product profit for purposes here can be *negative*.  I decided to use a binary indicator variable to detect whether a certain feature exists in each product or not.  That is I have the model:

$TotalProductProfit = Intercept + HasFeature$

where $TotalProductProfit$ is a vector of revenues for each product and $HasFeature$ is again a binary indicator of whether the feature I am interested in is present or not for the product whose revenue is being assessed.  To better understand the data consider the following table of fictional data:

```
ProductProfit  HasFeature

10                 1
40                 1
20                 0
50                 1
50                 1
50                 1
15                 0
-40                0
-30                1
-10                0
```

A plot of residuals vs. data looks like so:

[image]

The $R^2$ of this test came up $<.10$.  I am wondering how, considering that there is a clear difference in total contribution, the $R^2$ could be so low.  That is, grouping by the feature (adding all the revenue for the two categories) I found that those without the feature actually had a net negative contribution. Note that there are far more products with the feature than without it - the sample sizes are NOT equal.

Could it be that there are only a few products providing a disproportionate amount of weight?  Would the smaller sample size for the 'no feature' products accentuate this problem?

Comment: I am having trouble reconciling your title with the question. Are you perhaps mistaking $R^2$ for effect size?

Comment: @whuber You're right, I've changed the title to reflect the topic more accurately.  To clarify though, $R^2$ is one way of determining effect size, right?  I may be missing an important piece of information about it.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing how $R^2$ could be construed as an effect size, especially in this context. BTW, the phrase "sum totals" in the new title looks redundant. Ordinarily I wouldn't comment on that, but since your first paragraph is so vague, I am reaching for anything I can grasp to get clues concerning what you are doing. In your regression, what *exactly* are the variables? Is the "feature" a binary indicator or is it some larger categorical factor? What do the individual cases correspond to: a product, a sale, a group of products?

Comment: A plot of the data would help you and help us to think about the variability. But a detectable effect is quite compatible with a lot of unexplained variation, especially with this kind of sample size.

Comment: @Nick Does the added information help at all?

Comment: It's immensely helpful, thank you!  It clearly shows how much variation in revenue there is compared to the mean difference in revenues.  You don't need (or even want) a regression here; applying a two-sample t-test (the unequal variance Welch-Satterthwaite version) would be most appropriate. BTW, how can "revenue" in your table be negative? Are you perhaps referring to *profit*? (The distinction can be of more than technical interest: profit, as a *difference* of two variables, often can be better analyzed by separating revenue from costs and looking at them separately.)

Comment: +1 to @whuber's comments. Even better would be a paired histogram or dot plot or combined quantile plot. The two distributions show interesting differences.

Comment: I think it was just a labeling issue with the data I was looking at, it would technically be profit.  That's great to know.  This is probably a silly question but why would the regression do so poorly here but the t-test perform so well?  Could you also possibly explain why looking at the difference of revenue and cost variables would allow for better analysis?  If this requires a full answer I would certainly accept it.

Comment: The regression and the t-test are almost equivalent. The difference is largely that the t-test is more obviously focused on the question you want answered. In addition, the Welch-Satterthwaite version is easier to use in most software than an equivalent regression allowing for heteroscedasticity.

Comment: @Nick Perfect.  As expected the t-test was highly significant.  Thanks to both whuber and yourself.

Comment: The chief difference between *this particular* t-test and the regression is that the t-test allows for the two distributions to have different variances; the regression does not. The original regression surely was significant, anyway: significance and $R^2$ are not closely related.

Comment: @whuber You're right, it was significant.  I guess what worried me about the regression result was that they were not highly correlated, and I inferred that because they were not highly correlated that the presence of the feature did not actually *predict* profitability.